# Печать html

Tags: print, html

Здравствуйте, имеется страница php , с выводом данных из бд. Эта страница имеет некоторое css оформление. Но при печати остается только голый текст, без стилей, ну только позиционирование остается. Как заставить принтер печать html сохраняя стили?

Answer (score 1):

Придется написать CSS для вывода на печать с использованием
[media](http://Htmlbook.ru/HTML/link/media)

Comment: Ну что это значит?? мне обернуть текущей кодец @media print и все должно заработать?

Comment: Да, можно убрать то, что вы не хотите выводить на печать!

Answer (score 0):

Поместите это в head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="адрес к css">
```